# How to access feature attributes in feature set Arcade AGOL

Tags: javascript

i have did the same idea as this code and i have created feature set .
but i would like to get feature attributes from feature set that created at the end of code .

as example here ,i would like to show only specific column AddressCount
How could i achieve it ?

i need to continue this code to add in Arcade expression Arcgis online .

`

```
var portal = Portal("https://www.arcgis.com/");
var polyfs = FeatureSetByPortalItem(
    portal,
    "4dbbad3d6f694e0ebc7c3b4132ea34df",
    0,
    ["*"],
    false
);

var tablefs = FeatureSetByPortalItem(
    portal,
    "4dbbad3d6f694e0ebc7c3b4132ea34df",
    6,
    ["*"],
    false
);

// Create empty features array and feat object
var features = [];
var feat;

// Populate Feature Array
for (var t in tablefs) {
    var tableID = t["FeatureID"]
    for (var p in Filter(polyfs, "HydroID = "+tableID)){
        feat = {
            attributes: {
                FeatureID: tableID,
                Name: p["DPS_Region"],
                ModelID: t["ModelID"],                AddressCount: t["AddressCount"],
                MAX_TSTime: t["MAX_TSTime"],
            }
        }

    Push(features, feat)
    }
}

var joinedDict = {
    fields: [
        { name: "FeatureID", type: "esriFieldTypeString" },
        { name: "Name", type: "esriFieldTypeString" },  
        { name: "ModelID", type: "esriFieldTypeInteger" },
        { name: "AddressCount", type: "esriFieldTypeInteger" },
        { name: "MAX_TSTime", type: "esriFieldTypeString" },
    ],
    'geometryType': '',
    'features':features
};

// Return dictionary cast as a feature set 
return FeatureSet(Text(joinedDict));

`


Thanks in advance


i have converted the dictionary to feature set .
and i did 

     var   item_name = joinedDict.fields[3].name;
      return item_name

but the output of this code show me only  the name of field  but i would like to get the value of contain of attributes for this field
   
how to access in feature attributes of nested array dictionary  to obtain values of specific column .
```

Comment: could someone give me an idea , how to access feature attribute of feature set?